# Add dictionary values to dynamic object in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, microsoft-dynamics

I have a method that returns an object of dynamically created and would like to add the keys of a dictionary as the dynamic properties of this object and dictionary values ​​as values ​​of the properties of this new object. Below is the method but am having no success, someone help me understand and do this?

*is not a dictionary object is an object with values ​​(key and value) of a dictionary

```
public Object setObjectProperty(Dictionary<String, String> dictionary)
{
    dynamic newObj = new ExpandoObject();

    foreach (var word in dictionary)
    {
        newObj.word.Key = word.Value;
    }

    return (Object) newObj;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary<string, object>`, but it implements those methods explicitly.  Simply cast it to that type and then you can access the `Add` method:

```
public static Object setObjectProperty(Dictionary<String, String> dictionary)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> newObj = new ExpandoObject();

    foreach (var word in dictionary)
    {
        newObj.Add(word.Key, word.Value);
    }

    return newObj;
}
```